# I'm quite missing the Control+Tab shortcut of Visual Studio in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, visual-studio, shortcut

What is its equivalent in Xcode? Can I make my own custom shortcut in Xcode?

What other useful keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio that has a counterpart in Xcode?

Note: Control+Tab switches code back to recently opened code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this small arrow that will take you to the last edited code.

[image]

Those shortcuts are here :

[image]

Also swipe in the mouse will take you back to previous file.